# ¿Como Lograr Que Un Fragmento De Código se Repita Ilimitadamente?

Tags: java, android

Buenas a todos. Quiero encontrar la manera de poder lograr que un fragmento de código java se repita ilimitadamente en android, lo necesito implementar en un servicio, pero no quiero reiniciar el servicio nuevamente solo una parte del código de ese servicio (La clase implementadora del servicio es IntentService). Mi código actual o el que falla es un pequeño ciclo for() de suma y regreso a 0. Se los muestro:

```
for(int a=0;a<30;a++){
//Aqui va el codigo que se ejecuta

//Aqui devuelvo el valor 0 a "a" para que reinicie el proceso
a=0
}
```

Pero el problema que obtuve es que en android no avanzaba la operación en si la aplicación se quedo paraliza, como si el código se ejecutase de una manera que no dejara correr lo demás.  Si observan donde fallo o conocen otro método por favor comunicármelo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se puede usar un `for` :

```
 for (;;){
        ...
        ...
    }
```

un `while` :

```
boolean run = true;
while(run)
{
    ...
    ...
}
```

Pero prefiero usar un `Handler`.

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();

private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

      // Proceso a realizar.

      handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000); //ejecuta cada segundo.
    }
};

// Inicia handler.
handler.post(runnable);
```

o un `TimerTask`

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
  @Override
  public void run() {

    //Proceso a realizar.

  }
};

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(task, 0l, 1000l); //ejecuta cada segundo.
```

En el caso de Android hay que cuidar de no bloquear la UI realizando operaciones en el hilo principal.

Answer (score 2):

Si tu finalización es hacer un bucle infinito será mejor que lo hagas así:

```
while(true){
  //código
}
```

Como la condición siempre será cierta nunca saldrás de este bucle.

[java](/questions/tagged/java)

Comment: Gracias como se me pudo olvidar el ciclo while().